# alert confirming in-app purchase never appears

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have the usual store kit queue observer code:

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, 
    updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for t in transactions {
            switch t.transactionState {
            case .purchasing, .deferred: break // do nothing
            case .purchased, .restored:
                let p = t.payment
                if p.productIdentifier == myProductID {
                    // ... set UserDefaults to signify purchase ...
                    // ... put up an alert thanking the user ...
                    queue.finishTransaction(t)
                }
            case .failed:
                queue.finishTransaction(t)
            }
        }
}
```

The problem is what to do where I have the comment "put up an alert thanking the user". It seems simple enough: I'm creating a UIAlertController and calling `present` to show it. But it sometimes doesn't appear!

The trouble seems to have something to do with the fact that the runtime puts up its own alert ("You're all set"). I don't get any notice of this so I don't know this is happening. How can I cause my UIAlertController to be presented for certain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The Problem

You’ve put your finger on a serious issue of timing and information with regard to in-app purchases and StoreKit.

What’s going wrong here is that you (the store observer) receive `paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:)` and at that moment *two things happen simultaneously*, resulting in a race condition:

- The runtime puts up its “You’re all set” alert.
- You try to put your UIAlertController (and kick off various other activities).

As you rightly say, you don’t get *any* event to tell you when the user has dismissed the runtime’s “You’re all set” alert. So how can you do something *after* that alert is over?

Moreover, if you try to put up your alert at the same time that the system is putting up its “You’re all set” alert, *you will fail silently* — your UIAlertController alert will never appear.

### The Solution

The solution is to recognize that while the system’s “you’re all set” alert is up, *your app is deactivated*. We can detect this fact and register to be notified *when your app is activated again.* And *that* is the moment when the user has dismissed the “You’re all set” alert!

Thus it is now safe for you to put up your UIAlertController alert.

Like this (uses my `delay` utility, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24318861/341994; `vc` is the view controller we’re going to present the alert on top of):

```
let alert = UIAlertController( // ...
// ... configure your alert here ...
delay(0.1) { // important! otherwise there's a race and we can get the wrong answer
    if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {
        vc.present(alert, animated:true)
    } else { // if we were deactivated, present only after we are reactivated
        var ob : NSObjectProtocol? = nil
        ob = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            forName: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, 
            object: nil, queue: nil) { n in
                NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(ob as Any)
                delay(0.1) { // can omit this delay, but looks nicer
                    vc.present(alert, animated:true)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

I’ve tested this approach repeatedly (though with difficulty, because testing the store kit stuff works so badly), and it seems thoroughly reliable.

Comment: Thanks for the post. It's interesting and makes sense to me, but I can't believe it has to be so complex. I wonder if putting the alert code in `paymentQueue(_:removedTransactions:)` would remove/reduce the chance of the race condition? (I'm implementing similar behavior but haven't finished it and am not able to test it yet).

Comment: Well @rayx be sure to let me know if you come up with a better way! You can provide an alternative answer, I'll be quite happy. But if what you're saying is that it sounds like trying to test in-app purchases is damned near impossible, I'd have to agree, and I think you'll see that that is the case.

Comment: Sure. I'm adding the feature to my app, so I'll have to implement/workaround it some way. Will let you know when I get it done.

Comment: Hi @matt, could you please check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62336577/ios-a-default-alert-will-be-showed-after-purchasing-a-product-in-app-purchase

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI. I implemented a similar behavior in my app but I didn't observer the issue Matt described in the question. My app showed an alert to describe the failure and suggested action when a transaction failed. Below is my code:

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        switch transaction.transactionState {
        ...
        case .failed:
            let (reason, suggestion) = parsePaymentError(error: transaction.error)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            if let purchaseFailureHandler = self.purchaseFailureHandler {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    purchaseFailureHandler(reason, suggestion)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tested the code quite a few times with network connection error and user cancellation error. It worked perfectly for me.